# May i remove the /home directory? And how to know if there is any folder link to a specific folder?

Tags: macos

As the following picture shows:

[image]

The /home directory is empty. 
Can I remove the empty /home directory?
And how to know if there is any directory link to a specific directory?

Comment: See [What is /home directory in Mac OS used for?](https://superuser.com/questions/524632/what-is-home-directory-in-mac-os-used-for) - the answer is essentially nothing.  Note in Catalina if you do `ls -la /home` (not `ls -la /home/`) you'll see it is now a link to `/System/Volumes/Data/home` which would make deleting it cumbersome as the root directory is read only.  It still is generally not used but I'd leave it in case some old program wants it.